# Dar de alta registros ADO y VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

Estoy trabajando con VB 6.0 y ADO Clásico, estoy intentando insertar datos pero usando parámetros.

Conexión

```vb
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset

Public Function Conectar() As Boolean
    'TODO: Add 'Conectar' body here.
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=DESKTOP-SRPQ8P3\Kuky;Database=PruebaVB6;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
End Function


Public Sub Desconectar()
    'TODO: Add 'Desconectar' body here.
    On Local Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Método

```vb
Public Sub Create(entity As persona)
'TODO: Add 'Create' body here.
On Error GoTo tratarError
Dim cmd As New Command
Conectar
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Personas(Nombre, Direccion, Telefono) VALUES(@Nombre, @Direccion, @Telefono)"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Nombre", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, entity.Nombre)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Direccion", adVarChar, adParamInput, 150, entity.Direccion)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Telefono", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, entity.Telefono)
    .Execute
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
Desconectar
tratarError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

El error que me indica es que declare la variable `@Nombre`

Comment: Hola Pedro, detalles a tomar en cuenta, pero no directamente relacionados a tu pregunta: 1) El método `Desconectar` nunca se va a ejecutar, porque está definido después del `Exit Sub`. 2) Por defecto, VB6 pasa los parámetros usando `ByRef` (diferente a VB.NET), por lo que, a menos que tengas una razón para ello, casi siempre quieres especificar `ByVal` delante de los parámetros (ejemplo: `(ByVal entity As persona)`) 3) Cuidado con `As New ...`, no funciona de la misma manera que VB.NET.

Comment: @sstan Muchas gracias por tus recomendaciones, tienes razón sobre el método `Desconectar`, voy a revisar sobre `ByRef` y lo demás que me comenta voy a documentarme, me pasarón un proyecto antiguo para darle mantenimiento, años que no programo en VB6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he podido solucionar poniendo marcadores

```
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Personas(Nombre, Direccion, Telefono) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
```

Comment: ¿Alguien tiene alguna otra alternativa?

Comment: Aparentemente, el ADO clásico no maneja parámetros por nombres, a menos que se trate de una llamada a un stored procedure. Así que creo que tu solución es la correcta.

Comment: @sstan, es verdad con los stored procedure no tengo problemas asi como lo implemto en la pregunta funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear el parámetro antes de ejecutar la consulta.
Es por eso que no te reconoce el nombre de la variable `@nombre`, porque intenta insertar un valor en una variable que aun no esta declarada.